# Avoid Log in button in shareDialog feature of Facebook

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am using the share Dialog feature in my Android App. The login button which has inbuilt codes to facilitate the process of opening the session and some other functionality. Is there is any way to avoid using the login button and successfully use the shareDialog feature